# django: uwsgi not running with supervisor

Tags: django, uwsgi, supervisord

This is my uwsgi ini file,

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/root/projects/cbapis/cbapis
module=cbAPIs.wsgi:application
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=cbAPIs.settings.production
http=0.0.0.0:8002
workers=1
home=/root/projects/cbapis/cbapis/env
```

This is the django wsgi file,

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cbAPIs.settings.production")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When I run server with uwsgi, it runs fine,

```
uwsgi --ini cbapi_uwsgi_config.ini
```

Below is my supervisor conf for this project,

```
[program:djangocbapis]
command=uwsgi --ini /root/cbapi_uwsgi_config.ini
environment =
        DJ_DEV_SERVER_DB_NAME="****",
        DJ_DEV_SERVER_DB_USER="****",
        DJ_DEV_SERVER_DB_HOST="*****",
        DJ_DEV_SERVER_DB_PASSWORD="*****",
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
priority=400
stderr_logfile=/var/app/cbapis/log/cbapis.log
```

When I run this uwsgi server via supervisor, it does not run. I get the following error in the log file,

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

I have similar supervisor and uwsgi configuration for my other django projects in the same server, which are running fine with supervisor and uwsgi.

But I can't figure out why it cannot find python application while running with supervisor.

So, please help me in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give full path to `uwsgi` like `/usr/bin/uwsgi` or `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi`. If you are on ubuntu/linux then type command `which uwsgi` to get full path. It will work.

```
[program:djangocbapis]
command=/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /root/cbapi_uwsgi_config.ini
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
priority=400
stderr_logfile=/var/app/cbapis/log/cbapis.log
```

setup the environment variable in uwsgi `.ini` file.

```
env = DJ_DEV_SERVER_DB_NAME="****",
env = DJ_DEV_SERVER_DB_USER="****",
env = DJ_DEV_SERVER_DB_HOST="*****",
env = DJ_DEV_SERVER_DB_PASSWORD="*****",
```

Comment: still same error buddy, I don't think thats the blocking issue. I think If the path would have been the case, then it wouldn't have run without supervisor also.